# Uniform flow over a corrugated bed

Tags: homework-and-exercises, fluid-dynamics, waves

Water flows steadily with speed $U$ over a corrugated bed $y=-h+\epsilon \cos(kx)$, where $ \epsilon \ll h$, so that there is a time-independent disturbance $\eta(x)$ to the free surface, which would be at $y=0$ but for the corrugations. By writing the velocity components as:

$$ u= U + \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}$$

$$v=\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y}$$

where $\phi(x,y)$ denotes the velocity potential of the disturbance to the uniform flow, show that the linearized boundary conditions are:

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = U\frac{\partial \eta}{\partial x}$$  $$U\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} + g\eta = 0\qquad\text{on } y=0$$

$$\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial y} = -Uk\epsilon \sin(kx)\qquad\text{on } y=-h$$

and hence find $\eta(x)$.

I've managed to show the corrugated bed boundary and the first of the $y=0$ boundary, but I am struggling to show that $U\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} + g\eta = 0$  on $y=0$. I know that I have to use Bernoulli's principle for steady flow which says that $\frac{p}{\rho} +\frac{1}{2}|\mathbf{u}|^2 + g\eta$ should be constant along streamlines, but I'm not too sure how to do it.

I then also don't understand how to find $\eta(x)$. In past examples and our lecture notes they always start by saying we seek $\eta(x,t)$ (for time dependent) of the form $ \eta(x,t) = A\cos(kx-\omega t - \beta)$ with $k$ being wavenumber, $\omega$ being angular frequency and $\beta$ some phase shift, then using this to find a relationship called the 'dispersion relation'. I'm therefore not too sure how to explicitly determine $\eta(x)$.

Comment: Do you have some PDE of the kind $\eta(x,t)=f(\partial_x\eta,\partial_t\eta,...)$?

Comment: Hello! I have slightly edited your post, in my opinion improving the formatting. If you don't like it, feel free to rollback!

Comment: @Jonas It's much clearer, actually.

Comment: @Jonas thank you!